# Image Order in Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

After getting help from here I have my Lightbox working.  Thank you!

I have had to reorder the thumbnail images on the page, http://www.deccardy.com/portfolio-field-house.html for these to make sense to the viewer.

Is it possible to reorder the images in say the sequence of 1-6-2-7-3-8-4-9 etc?

This is how the remaining portfolio pages are currently arranged (w/o Lightbox) so that before/after images are above/below eachother.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There is no direct option for this by Lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of your images.

Comment: T/Y! This is what I have done on page with Lightbox...It means the thumbnail views are concurrent 1-10 and not as I would like them to appear 1-6-2-7 etc!